# Долгий запрос SQL LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть база транзакций определенных операций, выполняю запрос путем группировки по transactionId и дополнительных под.запросов что бы вывести прочую инфу. Выполняю запрос он ну очень долго выполняется, более 5 секунд. Подскажите можно ли такой запрос вообще оптимизировать?  Explain прикрепил

```html
 SELECT
      my_charger_meter.id,
      my_charger_meter.idTag,
      my_charger.name,
      my_charger.id AS name_id,
      my_charger_connectorId.conecrot AS conecrot,
      my_charger_meter.transactionId,
      min(my_charger_meter.timestamp) AS timestamp_start,
      max(my_charger_meter.timestamp) AS timestamp_stop,

      my_charger_meter.userId AS user_id,
      my_user.name AS user_name,
      my_user.surname AS user_surname


      FROM  my_charger_meter

      LEFT JOIN my_user  ON my_user.id=my_charger_meter.userId
      LEFT JOIN my_charger ON my_charger.idTag=my_charger_meter.idTag
      LEFT JOIN my_charger_connectorId ON my_charger_connectorId.idTag=my_charger_meter.idTag and my_charger_connectorId.connectorId=my_charger_meter.connectorId

      GROUP BY my_charger_meter.transactionId
      ORDER BY my_charger_meter.timestamp DESC LIMIT  0, 5
```

[image: Explain]

Comment: индекс по `transactionId` добавьте чтоль

Comment: вы уверены вообще что запрос выдает то что вам надо?

Comment: на остальные таблицы тоже индексы на столбцы, где должны быть внешние ключи, повесьте

Comment: запрос мне выдает то что надо. На мое удивление в базе my_charger_meter ключ для transactionId
 установлен